# How to have a reference to project's root folder with node-sass and sass-loader using webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, webpack, sass-loader

I've created a React project with `create-react-app` command, it uses webpack.

In order to use SASS I needed to eject with `npm run eject` command and to manually add SCSS loader inside loaders array, [as explained here](https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760).

This is my first time with React and I'm using a *per comonent style approach* which consist in importing a `.scss` file per component.

I have a global variables file in `~/my-project-folder/src/assets/styles/_variables.scss` and I want to import it from `~/my-project-folder/src/scenes/Auth/Login/styles/login.scss`, of course I don't want to do something like `@import '../../../assets/styles/_variables.scss'`.

I've seen that I can refer to SASS files inside `node_modules` folder this way: `@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";` so I'm wondering what is the way to refer to my project's root directory, i.e. `~/my-project-folder`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";  it will look for the bootstrap-sass in node_modules but when you want to import your global sass file in your other files then you have to give the relative path otherwise webpack will not able to resolve it for your. You can try to give public path in your webpack